# How to know if a software is installed using ActionScript

Tags: actionscript, air

I'm doing a application using actionScript(Air 2).
I want to know if a software is installed on user's pc, for example, I want to know if the user installed "Adobe Digital Editions", so I can open ebooks by that.
How to do that?
First I want read from the registry, but Air cannot read registry, and my boss said it's better not to run another "exe" app to read registry。Then I have no idea how to do that. Anyone has better suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If ADE associates itself with a particular file type or file extension, you could use NativeApplication.nativeApplication.getDefaultApplication("") to check what's associated with it and see if it matches the ADE program.. maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Check the default install locations for the application. If you cannot find what you're looking for, prompt the user to find it for you or install it.